# Way of casting in va_arg

Tags: c++, casting, variadic-functions

I'm doing some research about variadic functions and arguments.

I noticed that va_arg is able to cast objects into other objects. For example, when the next argument is a `char`, but you are using `va_arg` like it should be an `int`, it casts the `char` to an `int`:

Function call:

```
AddNumbers(3, 5, 'a', 20);
```

Function declaration:

```
int AddNumbers(int count, ...) {
    int result;

    va_list va;
    va_start(va, count);
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        result += va_arg(va, int);
    }
    return result;
}
```

So my question is: what kind of casting does this function use (C-style, dynamic_cast, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not exactly casting, because `va_arg` is a macro, not a function. So the type of `va_arg(va, int)` is *by construction* `int`.

But *promotions* do occur when calling the variadic function (except for the argument preceding the ellipsis.

So in `AddNumbers(3, 5, 'a', 20);`, the character `'a`' is promoted to an int. You can then either use it as an int as your code does, or convert it back to a char (a conversion not a cast) which is defined because the int value can be represented as a char (by construction)

Comment: How does it know that it should promote the variadic arguments to an int?

Comment: @MZeinstra - The compiler has the rules baked into it. `char` expressions are promoted to an `int` when passed to a variadic function

Comment: @StoryTeller What about classes? Those cannot be baked into the compiler, right?

Comment: @MZeinstra - It's undefined behavior to pass a variadic function anything other than a built-in type (pointers to anything are okay however).

Comment: @StoryTeller Hmm.. Okay, thanks :) (Although, I tried to give a class as a variadic argument, and give `va_arg` the base class of it, which did work)

Comment: @MZeinstra - Undefined also doesn't obligate it not to work :) Just means you can't rely on any specific thing happening when you do it. It makes for a shaky foundation for software.

Answer (score 4):

It has nothing to do with casting. In this case it works because of argument *promotion*.

When you use a varargs function, [integer types smaller than `int` (like e.g. `char`) are *promoted* to `int`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion).

That's why it works when passing character literals to the function. If you try some other type, like e.g. a floating point value, then it will no longer work.

As for what the [`va_arg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg) macro (it's mostly implemented as a macro) does, it is totally implementation dependent. It might not do any casting at all, but use some other form of [*type punning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning) instead.

Comment: So it basically assumes that it's the correct type, otherwise it causes a runtime error?

Comment: @MZeinstra - It isn't obligated to cause an error, it's just undefined behavior by the standard.

Comment: According to C standard (which is relevant since it is part of the C standard library accessible from C++) va_arg shall be implemented as a macro and the type of `va_arg(ap, type)` **is** type.

Comment: @MZeinstra C-style variable argument functions are not type-safe. For a type-safe C++ alternative look into [parameter packs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly:

C performs certain "casts" by default when calling a variadic function. GCC calls these [default argument promotions](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Calling-Variadics.html). They are:

- Signed or unsigned `char` and `short int` become signed or unsigned `int`.
- `float` becomes `double`.

This isn't really a matter of `va_arg` doing a cast *within* `AddNumbers`; instead, *when calling* `AddNumbers`, the caller promotes the arguments to `AddNumbers` as part of pushing them onto the stack for `AddNumbers` to use.